# Can't add custom font to Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, fonts, sprite-kit

I'm trying to add a downloaded font to Xcode and I've folowed every single step based on this link: http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

[image]

I added the font to my Xcode Project,
[image]

included it in Copy Bundle Resources (Build Phases),

[image]

and typed it in Fonts Provided by Application (in Info.plist).

[image]

Then I typed this in GameScene.swift inside didMoveToView

It has worked with other fonts but not with this one. This is really frustrating me and I've got no idea what the problem is, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the font is not always the name of the file. Try looking for the file and then opening in. It should automatically pull it up in font book, and the name of the font is located on the top bar. Simply enter that instead of the file name and it should work.

Comment: so, i replace everything?

Comment: @Gabe12 In _Step 5: Find the name of the font_ of the tutorial you refer to, check the name of your custom font logged in the console.

Comment: @Gabe12 No, keep everything the same except for when you enter the font name in your code. It might make things easier if you made the file name of your font the same as the actual font name, then you would be fine either way.

Comment: It works! Thank you all so much! ps: remember to like question so more people find it.