# Strange issue about the custom font

Tags: ios, fonts

I have added the font A to my application(set the Copy Bundle Resources & .plist). when I set the font of Label in storyboard, I can found the font A, and it can display normally.

But when I only set font of the Label in code, it crashed: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value "

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
     NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Shojumaru-Regular", size: 26)!,
     NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

I printed the font family, and if I have set the font in storyboard, it could print the font, but if I only set in code, can't find the font in fontfamily)

```
Shojumaru: Shojumaru-Regular
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code as text, not as images.

Comment: You need to use `Shojumaru-Regular` in your code, not `Shojumaru`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't add custom font to Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545330/cant-add-custom-font-to-xcode)

Comment: @rmaddy It also crashed.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a UIFont instance you want to initialize it with the *font name* not the font family name. So, in your example, you would need to initialize it with "Shojumaru-Regular".

It would end up looking something like this:

```
UIFont(name: "Shojumaru-Regular", size: 26)!
```

Comment: isnt in his screenshot he wrote same and it still crash?

Comment: I never saw his screenshot, so I can not speak for that, however, his example he posted used the font family name instead of the font itself.